# reducing/filtering an array

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I have an array which I want to filter out certain keys. Let's say `$subcats` equals this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 4
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 4
            [taxonomy] => category
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 5
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 5
            [taxonomy] => category
        )

)
```

All I want is the `term_ids` in it's own array.

I've tried foreach and array_values, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it at the moment. Should I be using array_filter?

So the result should be `$term_ids = array( 4, 5 );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$termIds = array_map(function($i) { return $i->term_id; }, $subcats);
```

This syntax requires PHP 5.3+.

Comment: My server only has PHP 5.2.14

Comment: Then you can reproduce the same thing using [`create_function`](http://php.net/create_function) or use a loop.

Comment: `function term_id($i) { return $i->term_id; } print_r( array_map( 'term_id', $subcats ) );`